Using generics with functions inside object
If I have function definition like this:
type TestFunc<ARGS> = (args: ARGS) => ARGS;

then in the implementation I can implement it as following:
const testFunc: TestFunc<number> = (args) => {
  return args;
};

But if I have that function definition inside interface like this:
interface TestInterface {
  testFuncInObj: <ARGS>(args: ARGS) => ARGS;
}

How do I pass number instead of ARGS generic type in the below implementation?
const testObj: TestInterface = {
  testFuncInObj: (args) => args,
};

If the type definition was like this:
interface TestInterface<ARGS> {
  testFuncInObj: (args: ARGS) => ARGS;
}

I could implement is as following:
const testObj: TestInterface<number> = {
  testFuncInObj: (args) => args,
};

But it is implemented like this one and I cannot change it.
interface TestInterface {
  testFuncInObj: <ARGS>(args: ARGS) => ARGS;
}

If I have below implementation. TS will complain that data does not exist in args.
const testObj: TestInterface = {
  testFuncInObj: (args) => {
    return {
      ...args,
      data: args.data,
    }
  },
};


"How do I pass number instead of ARGS generic type" - you can't. If the method is declared as generic, the implementation must support all possible types (and indeed that makes the whole method a bit useless, as there is only a single (correct) implementation). The fix is to change the interface declaration as you outlined.

"it is implemented like this one and I cannot change it" then you can't do what you are asking because testFuncInObj is not the same type as TestFunc<T>. The type of testFuncInObj is a generic function which means the caller chooses the type argument, not the implementer. Your choices are to fix the type of TestInterface to be generic (which you said you can't do) or to change your implementation of testFuncInObj to be something like args => args. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer or find a suitable duplicate. If not, what's missing?

@jcalz Thank you for the answer. Yes, this is the answer I needed: "The type of testFuncInObj is a generic function which means the caller chooses the type argument, not the implementer." So instead of defining type for the args, the following is more or less what I should do.
function hasDataProperty(args: any): args is { data: any } {   return args && typeof args === 'object' && 'data' in args; } const testObj: TestInterface = {   testFuncInObj: (args) => {     if (hasDataProperty(args)) return { ...args, data: args.data };     return args;   }, };

There are two flavors of generics in TypeScript, which differe in the scope of the generic type parameter.  There are generic types, like this:
type TestFunc<T> = (args: T) => T;

where the supplier of the value chooses the type argument, and there are generic functions, like this:
type TestFuncGen = <T>(args: T) => T;

where the caller of the function chooses the type argument. These are related but distinct types. Essentially TestFuncGen acts like TestFunc<T> for every possible T.  So a TestFuncGen must be a valid TestFunc<string> and a valid TestFunc<number> and a valid TestFunc<{data: object}>, etc., etc. Inversely, a TestFunc<T> for any given T is very unlikely to be a valid TestFuncGen.
You cannot simply move the scope of the generic type parameter without fundamentally changing who is in control of the generic type argument.

Your TestInterface is equivalent to
interface TestInterface {
    testFuncInObj: TestFunc2;
}

and so you cannot simply supply a TestFunc<{data: object}> there. You have to provide a function that accepts any possible input type and outputs the same type. The canonical implementation of that is just the identity function:
const testObj: TestInterface = {
    testFuncInObj: (args) => args
};

If you want to change that implementation so it inspects args and returns something else, you can do so, but TypeScript needs to believe that the return type is a subtype of the generic type of args, like
const testObj2: TestInterface = {
    testFuncInObj: (args) => args instanceof Object ?
        { ...args, anotherProp: 123 } : args
};

Playground link to code
